# Notational issues for point estimates

Tags: regression, random-variable, notation

In the most basic form, (as I recall), consider a random variable $X$
  which is defined over a probability space $\Omega$.
  Now, let us call a realization of $X$
  as $x$
 . As such, we can define mean, variance and other moments for $X$.

When we estimate a linear regression model, say we obtain an estimate for \beta
  as $\hat{\beta}=(x'x)^{-1}(x'y)$
 , the standard least standard least squares solution. Now, we know that $\hat{\beta}$ is a random variable, as we only observe a sample of the population, and the value of which depends on \epsilon. We then have $$var(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^{2}(x'x)^{-1}$$
  in the homoskedastic case. 
We can then do regular hypothesis testing $t$
  or $F$
  type tests. My question is, $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$
  conditional on our data, is not random anymore. I mean, for a fixed data set, we only have one $\hat{\beta}$.
  As such, in a random variable sense, it is the realization of the random process. (It is a realization $x$
  of the random variable $X$).
  What does $var(\hat{\beta)}$
 mean? Shouldnt different notation be used for the random variable and its realization?

Comment: You could ask exactly the same question about a coin flip, too.  That suggests the regression setting is irrelevant (and distracting)--and maybe it helps indicate what the answer is.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your comment..for a coin flip, I do not ask what the variance of a 'tails is'.  I ask what is the variance of the random variable that takes on heads or tails is (( p(1-p)). So is my concern a valid one, i.e. should different notation be used? Or am I grossly misunderstanding something? Thanks!

Comment: $\hat\beta$ is a random variable, just as the number of tails is in a sequence of independent coin flips.  You seem to be stating that the number of tails is "conditional on" the number of tails, because this is a "fixed data set."

Comment: It's a fair enough question really. Distinguishing the estimator as a random variable and an estimate for a specific dataset is a good thing. Instead, there are only some conventions that help: e.g. variance (for the estimator) versus standard error (for the estimate).

Comment: @whuber $\hat\beta_1$ is an estimator,  also random variable and estimate is a constant?

Comment: @Paari The estimate is the value of the estimator.  The *estimand* is a constant.  (If it weren't, there wouldn't be anything definite to estimate!)